# Yii2 change default Route to another namespace

Tags: php, yii2

the default route in Yii2 is @app/controllers/SiteController.
but If I build from beginning.

```
composer require yiisoft/yii2
```

then I create my own index.php and set the configure for the app

```
(new yii\web\Application($config))->run();
```

and the application is always try to local the defaultContoller in the app namespace. but If i put the SiteController in another namespace. it gives me 404 error,

index.php

```
require(__DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php');
require(__DIR__ . '/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php');

$config = require(__DIR__ . '/repo/config/web.php');

(new yii\web\Application($config))->run();
```

web.php

```
  'id' => 'repo', 
  'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),  
  'controllerNamespace' => 'repo\\controllers', 
  'defaultRoute' => 'site/index',
```

folder structure

```
/vendor
-yiisoft
/repo
-config
---web.php
-controllers
---SiteController.php
```

SiteController.php

```
<?php
namespace repo\controllers;

use Yii;
use yii\web\Controller;

class SiteController extends Controller{

  public function actionIndex(){

    echo 'welcome to the site';

  }
}
?>
```

if I give the SiteController.php namespace app/controllers it works,but once I change it back to repo/controllers it says page not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[yii\base\Application](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-application.html) object has a public property [controllerNamespace](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-application.html#$controllerNamespace-detail), which defaults to `app\\controllers`, you need to change it accordingly to changing default controller namespace.

Add this to your application config:

```
[
    ...
    'controllerNamespace' => 'app\\other\\namespace\controllers',
    ...
],
```

Default route is `site` (for [yii\web\Application](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-application.html)), it can be changed the same way ([defaultRoute](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-application.html#$defaultRoute-detail) property):

```
[
    ...
    'defaultRoute' => 'otherDefaultRoute',
    ...
],
```

Comment: I add it in the config file,but still get 404.

Comment: @tyan Please show application config, folder structure and controller code.

Comment: i find the problem , because I need to define the root alias.

Answer (score 3):

try this in you config file:

```js
'controllerNamespace' => 'newnamespace\controllers',
'defaultRoute' => 'new/index',
```

Answer (score 1):

I found I forgot to define the root alias.

```
// $className is a fully qualified class name without the leading backslash
$classFile = Yii::getAlias('@' . str_replace('\\', '/', $className) . '.php');
```

so If I define the root alias @repo in the configuration. then it works

```
  'aliases' => [
    '@repo' => dirname(__DIR__),
  ],
```